# Rails missing param password with blowfish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, blowfish

I am using the blowfish gem to encrypt passwords for my users (`user` model).

in the schema I don't have a `password` field anymore but in the rails console I can (and have to) run `user.password = "xxx"` and `user.password_confirmation = "xxx"` in order to be able to call `user.save`. This works in the rails console but I have a webform where a user is logically able to edit his/her password.

This is my `edit.html.erb`

```
 <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %> 
    <%= submit_tag("Edit User") %>
 <% end %>
```

the parital in `_form.html.erb` that pertains to passwords is this

```
 <table>
   ...
 <tr>
    <th>Password</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:password) %></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <th>Confirm Password</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:password_confirmation)%></td>
 </tr>
```

In my `users_controller.rb` I require `login password password_confirmation` like this

```
    def update
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       @user.update_attributes(user_params)
       if @user.save
         flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
         redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @user.id)
       else
         flash[:notice] = "Error Updating"
         render('edit')
        end  
     end
```

and

private

```
def user_params
  r = params.require(:user)
  r.require(:login)
  r.require(:password)
  r.require(:password_confirmation)
  r.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :login, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

The issue is not when I submit a complete form, that updates fine. The issue is that when I leave the password field empty, instead of rendering the edit form again it gives me a `Action Controller: Exception` `param not found: password` and points to the `r.require(:password)` line of the `user_params` function

EDIT

I commented the two require lines out and validate the presence of login,password,password_confirmation in the model. However now I get this error

`undefined method`user' for #`pointing to the`@user.upadte_attributes(user_params)` line.

I still need to require `:user` and then `.permit(.....)` for the strong parameters in Rails 4 right?

EDIT 2 -- Update Method in `users_controller.rb`

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
    redirect_to(user_path(@user.id))
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Error Updating"
    render('edit')
  end  
 end
```

and `user params`
   private

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :position, :pictureString)
end
```

The Error Message:

```
undefined method `user' for #<User:0x007f4d482b1af0>
Extracted source (around line #36):
34 def update
35 @user = User.find(params[:id])
36 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
37  flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
38  redirect_to(user_path(@user.id))
39 else

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36:in `update'
```

EDIT

Some further investigation revealed this:

If I leave the `.permit(....)` out of the `user_params` function (i.e. have it only read `params[:user]`) then I don't get the undefined method error but the expected `forbidden attributes` error. Maybe this helps you find what's wrong.

Comment: You get the error because of this line: `r.require(:password)` - so of course if it is empty you'll get this message. If you are trying to validate presence of the password attribute, it should be done in the model.

Comment: thanks, the tutorial I was following put the requires in the controller not the model

Comment: Cool, so you've answered your own question.

Comment: not quite, when I commented the two require lines for password out of the controller action and added the `validates_presence_of` in the model it gives me another error

Comment: Speculating, but ``undefined method user`` makes it sound like you forgot the "@" prefix, i.e. you wrote ``user`` where you should have written ``@user``.

Comment: I posted my update method up top... the error is in the update method at the `if @user.update...` line... the same happens in my create action at the `if @user.save` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strong Parameters are *not* meant for form validation.  They are meant for security purposes to replace the `attr_accessible` macro used at the model level.

Form validation should either either be performed client side, or by passing the params to some model that performs the validation (which will in turn call `update_attributes` if deemed valid).

Comment: the validation is in the model... The question is why does the params.require.permit not work anymore... does it have something to do with RESTful routes?

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting complete with stacktrace (or update the code posted) - `undefined method 'user'` can't be coming from the code you posted since you aren't calling `user` anywhere in this code.

Comment: I posted the error message. I think this might have something to do with RESTful routes since I haven't changed those lines in a while and they always used to work. I just can't figure out what the error means... I don't see `user` used as a method anywhere

Comment: omg... i had `validates_presence_of :user` in my model instead of :login ..... no wonder it couldn't find it ... weird that it didn't point any error to the model but to the controller...